# How to launch Edge with some cmd line args?

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-edge, command-line-arguments

I'm using Windows 10. According to Microsoft Edge DevTools Protocol [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-protocol/), I need to launch Edge with the `--devtools-server-port` cmd line arg.

i tried to do so via Console, but got an error:

> 'MicrosoftEdge.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

After checking out this [thread](https://superuser.com/q/949998/332179), it turns out that there is apparently some magic with launching Edge by not using standard shortcut in Start menu.

How can we launch Edge with some cmd line args?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line#31281412

Comment: @Clayton: Tried all of those suggestion. While they launch Edge, none seems to be passing `--devtools-server-port` cmd line arg to it.

Comment: Are you running an `Insider Preview build` of windows? From your link `The Microsoft Edge DevTools Protocol is currently in preview and works only on Windows Insider Preview builds.`

Comment: @Clayton: Holy moly, you're right! I'm on the stable version on Win 10. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov May I request you to add a formal answer to this thread, if you were able to resolve the problem yourself because of incorrect OS version that you were using. It can be really helpful for future readers who face the same problem.

Comment: @RBT: Sure, please see my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1353540/332179) below.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by **@Clayton** in comments to my question, in order to be able to use Microsoft Edge DevTools Protocol you have to make sure you actually have it in your system first. At the moment, this means that you should [update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/04/30/how-to-get-the-windows-10-april-2018-update/#5VXkQMU41CJzZPER.97) your Windows 10 at least to April 2018 Update (version 1803) or later (see the link in my question for reference).

Then, you can launch Edge with DevTools Protocol server enabled by creating a shortcut on your Desktop with the command like this as a `Target`:

```
MicrosoftEdge.exe --devtools-server-port 9220 http://localhost:5000
```

After launching Edge with this shortcut, you now able to connect to Edge, for instance, with Visual Studio Code just like you used to do so to connect to Chrome. Here is a sample of a corresponding setup from `launcn.json`:

```
{
    "type": "edge",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Edge",
    "port": 9220,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

Of course for this to work, you need to have the [Debugger for Edge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge) extension installed in VS Code.